# Embed spreadsheet table in google doc with apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm wondering if there's a way to embed a spreadsheet table into a google doc using apps script.

I am aware that you can do it by copy/pasting the table into the google doc, but is there a way to do it with apps script?

*Edit*

Using @Cooper and @Alberto Molina's answers, I came up with the following code, it imports and inserts a table

```
var sheet = SpreadSheetApp.openById("").getSheets()[0];
var docBody = DocumentApp.openById("").getBody();
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var elem = docBody.findText("").getElement();  
var parent = elem.getParent();
var idx = docBody.getChildIndex(parent);
docBody.insertTable(++idx, values);
```

This code inserts a "raw" table like so 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s43Wl.png)

I want the changes to the original table to affect the table in the google document. So basically I want to insert it like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p1yH.png)

The idea I currently have is :

```
docBody.insertTable(++idx, values).setLinkUrl(**???**);
```

But I don't know what to set the URL to

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Hello, I just Edited my question with further explanation and research efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function table(){
  var ss = SpreadSheetApp.getCurrentSheet();
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Sample Document'); // Or find one by name/ID
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var dataYouWant = ss.getRange("A1:D4").getValues(); // stores a 2D array with the values
  table = body.appendTable(dataYouWant); // pastes table in doc

  table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true); // Example of how to edit table, this sets the header bold.
}
```

Since you did not give any existing code or specifics this is a very broad solution. But in esence what you need is to get the values (in a 2D array) and then paste them into the doc’s body with `appendTable()`.

[Here’s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) some documentation on using docs through GAS.
[Here’s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table) some documentation on the class that handles Doc’s tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This goes into Code.gs in the Documents script editor and it opens up another spreadsheeet to get it's data.

```
function addNewTable() {
  var data=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId").getSheetByName('SheetName').getDataRange().getValues();
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();//run from active document
  doc.getBody().appendTable(data);
}
```

Image of data from SpreadSheet:

[image]

Image of table in document:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is it possible to link the tables - have changes to the table in the spreadsheet affect the table that's in the google doc? Just like it would do if you manually copy/paste a table into a google doc